# ReferenceError: dhtmlXCellObject is not defined / TypeError: this._hdrInit is not a function

Tags: typeerror, dhtmlx, referenceerror

I have a map with google maps api, and a table, which I want to connect to the map with dHTMLx Layout. (I'm a beginner, so sorry about the question, but I haven't found any solution yet, and I already checked the references in the code) I have this code:

```
<head>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=utf-8">

    <title>Map</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dhtmlxlayout_dhx_skyblue.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dhtmlxlayout.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="dhtmlxlayout.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dhtmlxcommon.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dhtmlxcontainer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dhtmlxlayout_deprecated.js"></script>

</head> 

<body>

    <script>

        var dhxLayout = new dhtmlXLayoutObject(document.body, "2U");
        dhxLayout.cells("a").setText("Térkép"); 
        dhxLayout.cells("a").attachURL("googleapi.html");
        dhxLayout.cells("b").setText("Táblázat"); 
        dhxLayout.cells("b").setWidth(500); 
        dhxLayout.cells("b").attachURL("list.html");

    </script> 

</body>
```

What does the 2 error means? ReferenceError: dhtmlxCellObject is not defined & TypeError: this._hdrInit is not a function both in dhtmlxlayout.js
What should I correct? The googleapi.html and list.html are working fine separate.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a special option for using google maps in dhtmlx layout - attachMap

[Online sample](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxLayout/samples/04_attach_components/16_gmaps.html)
and 
  [Documentation](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/layout__attach_google_map.html)
will help you

By the way Google doesn't allow to use its servise in iframes

Plus if you don't use deprecated dhtmlx methods, you don't need to include this file in the page